# I got this error System.StackOverflowException was unhandled HResult=-2147023895 Message=Exception_WasThrown InnerException:

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled   HResult=-2147023895   Message=Exception_WasThrown   InnerException:

```
 public partial class dridviewinser_update_Delete : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
        string connectstringweb = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydatabase"].ConnectionString;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindgridview();
        }

        private void bindgridview()
        {
            //this is property
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstringweb);
            con.Open();
            string query = "gridview_select_bindgrid";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            grdviewdata.DataSource = dt;
            grdviewdata.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            bindgridview();
        }

        protected void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstringweb);
            con.Open();
            string query = "dridview_insert";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Insert Successfull!");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have an extra `}` at the end of your code

Comment: `bindgridview();` is not needed at the bottom of the `bindgridview()` Method this is what the debugger was designed for so that you can debug and step through your own code

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `bindgridview();` from within the same method.  Thus, it will call itself over and over and over until there is a stack overflow.

I can't tell by your code what would be the appropriate fix.  Can you just delete that line from the bottom of the method?  Or possibly you made an error and meant to call another method.  Either way, if you debug your application and step through the code, you will see that it enters that method over and over again without something to stop it from doing so.

Comment: Thank you so much I deleted the line now the code is working.